# why eclipse m2e error "add a version or custom suffix using name template in advanced settings"

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

In eclipse when I am trying to import a **muti pom project** from **git** or **svn** through the **m2e plugin**, it's giving me the error:

> add a version or custom suffix using name template in advanced
>   settings because of the project xxx already exists

I am sure some of the projects are not in the /workspace folder

Answer (score 8):

You can use the "Advanced" option at bottom of import window, "Name template" select "[artifactId]-[version]","Profiles" fill the project name and version, eg:helloWord-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

just test, and good luck

Answer (score 1):

[Gherkin.G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6467160/gherkin-g) answer OR:

1. Expand the `Advanced` option at the bottom of the **import window**.
2. - Set the *name* that you want in the`Name template` dropdown which can be used as a field.
   - OR, open the dropdown and select your default project name.
3. When set, your project will be **enabled** for selection without any warning.
4. Select it, and proceed with the import.